# How to access multidimensional JSON object

Tags: jquery

I am sending JSON encode array list which gives following output:

```
[
  "2017",
  "4",
  "2017-04-28",
  "2017-4-30",
  "6",
  36,
  42,
  {
    "2017-4-1": "",
    "2017-4-2": "",
    "2017-4-3": 1,
    "2017-4-4": 1,
    "2017-4-5": "",
    "2017-4-6": "",
    "2017-4-7": "",
    "2017-4-8": "",
    "2017-4-9": "",
    "2017-4-10": "",
    "2017-4-11": "",
    "2017-4-12": "",
    "2017-4-13": 2,
    "2017-4-14": "",
    "2017-4-15": 1,
    "2017-4-16": 3,
    "2017-4-17": "",
    "2017-4-18": 1,
    "2017-4-19": "",
    "2017-4-20": "",
    "2017-4-21": "",
    "2017-4-22": "",
    "2017-4-23": "",
    "2017-4-24": "",
    "2017-4-25": "",
    "2017-4-26": 1,
    "2017-4-27": 2,
    "2017-4-28": "",
    "2017-4-29": "",
    "2017-4-30": 2
  }
]
```

I can access the above array using jQuery:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(response);
var dateYear = json[0];
```

but how to access this data

```
"2017-4-1": "",
"2017-4-2": "",
"2017-4-3": 1,
"2017-4-4": 1,
"2017-4-5": "",
"2017-4-6": "",
"2017-4-7": "",
"2017-4-8": "",
"2017-4-9": "",
"2017-4-10": "",
"2017-4-11": "",
"2017-4-12": "",
"2017-4-13": 2,
"2017-4-14": "",
"2017-4-15": 1,
"2017-4-16": 3,
"2017-4-17": "",
"2017-4-18": 1,
"2017-4-19": "",
"2017-4-20": "",
```

Comment: Loop through the properties of the 8th element of your array, eg: `arr[7]`

Comment: How can u give the exact code it would be very helpful

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

To do this you just need to loop over the 8th element of the array, like this:

```js
var dateYear = ["2017","4","2017-04-28","2017-4-30","6",36,42,{"2017-4-1":"","2017-4-2":"","2017-4-3":1,"2017-4-4":1,"2017-4-5":"","2017-4-6":"","2017-4-7":"","2017-4-8":"","2017-4-9":"","2017-4-10":"","2017-4-11":"","2017-4-12":"","2017-4-13":2,"2017-4-14":"","2017-4-15":1,"2017-4-16":3,"2017-4-17":"","2017-4-18":1,"2017-4-19":"","2017-4-20":"","2017-4-21":"","2017-4-22":"","2017-4-23":"","2017-4-24":"","2017-4-25":"","2017-4-26":1,"2017-4-27":2,"2017-4-28":"","2017-4-29":"","2017-4-30":2}];

for (var key in dateYear[7]) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + dateYear[7][key]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cant access the value using:dateYear[7][key]

Comment: Why is that? As you can see from the snippet above it works fine based on the sample data you provided in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can access key in an object like this: `for(key in obj)`

```js
var obj = [
  "2017",
  "4",
  "2017-04-28",
  "2017-4-30",
  "6",
  36,
  42,
  {
    "2017-4-1": "",
    "2017-4-2": "",
    "2017-4-3": 1,
    "2017-4-4": 1,
    "2017-4-5": "",
    "2017-4-6": "",
    "2017-4-7": "",
    "2017-4-8": "",
    "2017-4-9": "",
    "2017-4-10": "",
    "2017-4-11": "",
    "2017-4-12": "",
    "2017-4-13": 2,
    "2017-4-14": "",
    "2017-4-15": 1,
    "2017-4-16": 3,
    "2017-4-17": "",
    "2017-4-18": 1,
    "2017-4-19": "",
    "2017-4-20": "",
    "2017-4-21": "",
    "2017-4-22": "",
    "2017-4-23": "",
    "2017-4-24": "",
    "2017-4-25": "",
    "2017-4-26": 1,
    "2017-4-27": 2,
    "2017-4-28": "",
    "2017-4-29": "",
    "2017-4-30": 2
  }
];

var last = obj[7];
for(key in last) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below jQuery code. run one **`for()`** loop to get all array data, then check for **object** then add one more child `for()` loop to access another child data which is in object type.

Check the snippet below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof myArr[i] === "object") {
          for (var sec = 1; sec < 30; sec++) {
            $("ul").append("<li><span>" + myArr[i]["2017-4-" + sec] + "</span></li>")
          }
        } else {
          $("ul").append("<li>" + myArr[i] + "</li>")
        }

      }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myArr = [
    "2017",
    "4",
    "2017-04-28",
    "2017-4-30",
    "6",
    36,
    42,
    {
      "2017-4-1": "object 1",
      "2017-4-2": "object 2 ",
      "2017-4-3": 1,
      "2017-4-4": 1,
      "2017-4-5": "",
      "2017-4-6": "",
      "2017-4-7": "",
      "2017-4-8": "",
      "2017-4-9": "",
      "2017-4-10": "",
      "2017-4-11": "",
      "2017-4-12": "",
      "2017-4-13": 2,
      "2017-4-14": "",
      "2017-4-15": 1,
      "2017-4-16": 3,
      "2017-4-17": "",
      "2017-4-18": 1,
      "2017-4-19": "",
      "2017-4-20": "",
      "2017-4-21": "",
      "2017-4-22": "",
      "2017-4-23": "",
      "2017-4-24": "",
      "2017-4-25": "",
      "2017-4-26": 1,
      "2017-4-27": 2,
      "2017-4-28": "",
      "2017-4-29": "",
      "2017-4-30": 2
    }
  ]

  // Fetching data
  for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof myArr[i] === "object") {
      for (var sec = 1; sec < 30; sec++) {
        $("ul").append("<li><span>" + myArr[i]["2017-4-" + sec] + "</span></li>")
      }
    } else {
      $("ul").append("<li>" + myArr[i] + "</li>")
    }

  }
});
```

```css
li span {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul></ul>
```

Comment: I don't want to iterate the given array I just want to compare the value against a specified value

Comment: i have given you code according to your question which you asked, so what value you want to compare. write properly in question